# Getting/Forwarding Audit events from kubernetes clusters

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks, amazon-eks

I need to filter and forward audit log events from kubernetes to a webhook.  Is there a mechanism that I can use that works for on-prem clusters, GKE, EKS, and AKS?

I can set up EKS to log the the audit events to Cloudwatch logs, Azure to log these to diagnostic logging, GCP logs to stackdriver (google seems to reformat them), but i would prefer a single mechanism for all.  I know that kubernetes supports starting the api server with some arguments for specifying audit destinations, but i don't really have any control over that for managed cloud solutions like eks/aks/gke.  If I can hook these events from a container somehow that would be great.  The event api (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#event-v1-core) however seems be a different class of event, which doesn't contain the user information that I need

The events I am looking for are the audit events such as:

```
{
    "kind": "Event",
    "apiVersion": "audit.k8s.io/v1",
    "level": "Request",
    "auditID": "b5944e24-548d-4b5e-a5c7-218316d20ff1",
    "stage": "ResponseComplete",
    "requestURI": "/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/clusterrolebindings/system:persistent-volume-binding",
    "verb": "get",
    "user": {
        "username": "aksService",
        "groups": ["system:masters", "system:authenticated"]
    },
    "sourceIPs": ["172.31.20.52"],
    "userAgent": "kubectl/v1.13.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/cff46ab",
    "objectRef": {
        "resource": "clusterrolebindings",
        "name": "system:persistent-volume-binding",
        "apiGroup": "rbac.authorization.k8s.io",
        "apiVersion": "v1beta1"
    },
    "responseStatus": {
        "metadata": {},
        "code": 200
    },
    "requestReceivedTimestamp": "2019-10-24T17:38:56.846112Z",
    "stageTimestamp": "2019-10-24T17:38:56.848507Z",
    "annotations": {
        "authorization.k8s.io/decision": "allow",
        "authorization.k8s.io/reason": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how this is going to suit collectively for GKE, EKS, and AKS. But if you felt that this is going to be a feature request with GKE, feel free to open one using [this help center article](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers?hl=th#feature_requests).

Comment: This sounds like you're looking for a custom logging solution for each of your clusters. You can disable logging from the cloud providers and instead use your own custom fluentd

Comment: Otherwise, you can't change kubelet flags for hosted k8s offerings and the built in logging for each won't work for all. Using your own custom logging to send logs on prem is your best bet.